# How to convert this "JavaScript" to a "Jquery"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, converters

I have a HTML page that is used in chrome kiosk mode (for permanent display, not regular website usage)

This page displays information and has a jquery slideshow and on top of that slideshow is an animation that is achived via javascript.

This is the script for it:

```js
function ovl00() {
    document.getElementById('OV00').style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById('OV01').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV02').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV03').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV04').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV05').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV06').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV07').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV08').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV09').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV10').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV11').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV12').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV13').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV14').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV15').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV16').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV17').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV18').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV19').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV20').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV21').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV22').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV23').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV24').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV25').style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById('OV26').style.opacity = '0';
    setTimeout(ovl01, 10702);
}
function ovl01() {
    document.getElementById('OV01').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl02, 10702);
}
function ovl02() {
    document.getElementById('OV02').style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById('OV00').style.opacity = '0';
    setTimeout(ovl03, 10702);
}
function ovl03() {
    document.getElementById('OV03').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl04, 10702);
}
function ovl04() {
    document.getElementById('OV04').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl05, 10702);
}
function ovl05() {
    document.getElementById('OV05').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl06, 10702);
}
function ovl06() {
    document.getElementById('OV06').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl07, 10702);
}
function ovl07() {
    document.getElementById('OV07').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl08, 10702);
}
function ovl08() {
    document.getElementById('OV08').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl09, 10702);
}
function ovl09() {
    document.getElementById('OV09').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl10, 10702);
}
function ovl10() {
    document.getElementById('OV10').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl11, 10702);
}
function ovl11() {
    document.getElementById('OV11').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl12, 10702);
}
function ovl12() {
    document.getElementById('OV12').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl13, 10702);
}
function ovl13() {
    document.getElementById('OV13').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl14, 10702);
}
function ovl14() {
    document.getElementById('OV14').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl15, 10702);
}
function ovl15() {
    document.getElementById('OV15').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl16, 10702);
}
function ovl16() {
    document.getElementById('OV16').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl17, 10702);
}
function ovl17() {
    document.getElementById('OV17').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl18, 10702);
}
function ovl18() {
    document.getElementById('OV18').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl19, 10702);
}
function ovl19() {
    document.getElementById('OV19').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl20, 10702);
}
function ovl20() {
    document.getElementById('OV20').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl21, 10702);
}
function ovl21() {
    document.getElementById('OV21').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl22, 10702);
}
function ovl22() {
    document.getElementById('OV22').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl23, 10702);
}
function ovl23() {
    document.getElementById('OV23').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl24, 10702);
}
function ovl24() {
    document.getElementById('OV24').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl25, 10702);
}
function ovl25() {
    document.getElementById('OV25').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl26, 10702);
}
function ovl26() {
    document.getElementById('OV26').style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(ovl00, 10702);
}
```

The reason why I want to convert this is (I guess) mostly simple: Doing some research I learned that Chrome implements some energy saving options that when a tab/window is not the "Active" one, javascript triggers are slowed down to just once a minute.

This would obviously de-sync and mess up the whole slideshow+animation.
From what I can see and learned, jquery is not affected by that.

So I want to make the HTML page fail/future proof to avoid that timer throttling.

At current setup, the PC that displays the HTML in Kiosk mode is in dual display mode: Meaning that chrome is in fullscreen via HDMI 2 and work is done on the main monitor via HDMI 1.

So this makes chrome (from a viewpoint of windows) quite often just a background app.

My worries are, that sooner or later this chrome implementation messes up the current slideshow...

I should also note, that I know next-to-nothing about coding and did the whole HTML and scripts via Google searches and Copy+Paste, so I hope that my explanation of this is well enough for you real coders to understand and someone here can direct me maybe to a converter app (Like wav to mp3 but for scripts) or similar.

Any help appreciated!

-Sabrina

Comment: *The reason why I want to convert this is* - it's a maintenance nightmare.   I can't believe you created 26 lines/functions all the same.  I would have given up after 3 or 4...

Comment: Your whole `ovl00` can be replaced with `$(".slideshow .ov").hide()` if you add classes in the correct place (no html provided, so can't advise this).  And all the others could be a single `$(".slideshow .ov.active").fadeOut().next().addClass(".active").fadeIn()` with a check for last one - or even skip fadeOut/fadeIn and use css `.ov { opacity:0 } .ov.active { opacity: 1}` - lot's of options :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Seems you know your stuff, so I'm trying to add more details (in hope for help) You can find the full html here [link] (https://sabrina-ambiencemusic.com/SLD/SL9.html) It contains the Javascript+Jquery hybrid. And here is a short HDMI grab visually showing what I try to achieve [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oFMEIGWDW-_sB-haQCQRxpS54jxXv5Oy/view) And the reasoning is mostly for avoiding potention throttling and ensuring proper function. Also in the current setup the fade in animation gets out of sync after a few hours displayed ...

Comment: As for the idea about using class. I tried that in the past, but the result wasn't what I hoped for (in regards to the animation). But it could be due to my very limited coding knowledge, which is also why I created 26 lines of the same function (I don't know any better) Also, thanks for your help so far and potentionally future help! Also trying with dreamweaver your above suggestions now (:

Answer (score 2):

The only 2 types of javascript queries you've used are

```
document.getElementById('OV00').style.opacity = '1';
setTimeout(ovl02, 10702);
```

And the jQuery equivalent of the first one is

```
$("#OV00").css({ opacity: "1" });
```

I don't think there is a different function for setTimeout in jQuery, the same will work. So you just have to change every line containing document.getElement... to the one I've mentioned with it's appropriate ID and opacity value.

So finally that's what you asked for. But I don't think this actually solves your problem of chrome throttling your animation. jQuery is not different from JavaScript, they both get executed by the same javascript engine present in the browser. jQuery is just a library that provides an easier syntax for developers to write complex javascript and that is almost obsolete after the arrival of various frontend javascript frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! At this time I'm lucky and my animation is (not yet) throttled or broken, but I appreciate the info about jQuery being executed by the same engine as javascript. Gives me a fair warning, that my animation might get broken sooner or later anyways ...